# GDPR extension Captcha

Tags: gdpr

It appears that Google Captcha does not seem to work with the GDPR extension.

I have a fully working setup using profiles as normal on site - which can be seen here

https://peoples-press.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=57

However, on this form,

https://peoples-press.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/gdpr/comms-prefs/update

I have captcha activated but it does not show on form. If I click Save then it alerts me to complete Captcha despite it not being possible. Form works fine if I deactivate Captcha.

Joomla 3.8.7 and Civicrm 5.1

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want a captcha on the form considering it's authenticated either via hash or via login. *EDIT* Just looked and saw you're using it as a signup form as well.

Comment: You would not advise using it as a sign up page?

Comment: I probably wouldn't but I'm struggling to put my finger on exactly why...

Comment: It could be used for sign up pages as it allows for profiles and has anon access, we haven't yet tested it with captcha. If you could create an issue on the git repo https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update, we're releasing a new version which has the ability to include captcha. It will be available from tommorrow (v2.6).